# Linear Discriminant Analysis with p>1 How does X transpose Sigma can get multiplied

Tags: bayesian, discriminant-analysis

I'm reading Bishop books on Statistical Learning, and ran into the Gaussian density function for LDA when p > 1.

$$P(x|k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^p|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({x'}-{\mu_k'})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({x'}-{\mu_k'})
\right)$$

But I am wondering how can this terms be multiplied? I am under the assumption that X is a feature vector of 1xp and if sigma is pxp why does it gets transpose first?

$$({x'}-{\mu_k'})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({x'}-{\mu_k'})$$

Wouldn't this make more sense:

$$({x'}-{\mu_k'}){\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({x'}-{\mu_k'})^T$$

Comment: Notations and formula views differ in sources. Vector can be row, or can be column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If notation makes no sense, but *does* make sense with minimal changes, make those changes mentally.

There is no hard-and-fast convention on whether an author considers $x$ to be a row or a column vector, although a row vector interpretation is more common. Here, Bishop obviously uses $x\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}$ as a column vector, so the term on the left of the covariance matrix needs to be transposed.